# How to properly nest if statements in VHDL

Tags: if-statement, nested, vhdl

```
process (bit1,bit2,j)
begin
if j = '1' then

if (bit1 = '1' and bit2 = '1') then
V <= '1' xor g;
bit3 <= '1' xor g;
elsif (bit1 = '1' and bit2 = '0') then
V <= '0' xor g;
bit3 <= '0' xor g;
elsif (bit1 = '0' and bit2 = '0') then
V <= '1' xor g;
bit3 <= '1' xor g;
elsif (bit1 = '0' and bit2 = '1') then
V <= '0' xor g;
bit3 <= '0' xor g;
end if;

else

if j = '0' then

if (bit1 = '1' and bit2 = '1') then
V <= '0' xor g;
bit3 <= '0' xor g;
elsif (bit1 = '1' and bit2 = '0') then
V <= '1' xor g;
bit3 <= '1' xor g;
elsif (bit1 = '0' and bit2 = '0') then
V <= '0' xor g;
bit3 <= '0' xor g;
elsif (bit1 = '0' and bit2 = '1') then
V <= '1' xor g;
bit3 <= '1' xor g;
end if;

end if;

end if;

end process;
```

Hello,
I am stuck on one Task for VHDL programming and I could really use some help.

The Task is to programm a two complement adder with corresponding flags set after the addition.

As I write my code the first thing I do is that initialize my two inputs so that both of the vectors have same length. After that comes carry etc.

The problem occurs in `process (bit1,bit2,j)`

I don't know what is causing this error but my V and bit 3 are never correctly initialized. And I suppose it is happening because of too many if statements or because I am nesting them wrong. Also the compiler does not say anything.

Comment: Please indent the code according to the if nesting.

Comment: Here only the process

Comment: `g` is missing in the process sensitivity list.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements aren't the problem. Compilers may have a practical limit on how deep you can nest your if blocks, but that limit is definitely a bit higher than 3 levels.

As Martin mentioned, you reference a signal called 'g' that is used as an input to your combinational logic, but isn't listed in your sensitivity list. That's often reported as a warning, not an error. In the state it's in, most simulators won't execute the process when there's an event on 'g'. That could result in uninitialized values.